# Need help in setup of Redshift and Scala using Play

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, amazon-redshift, scalikejdbc

I am new to Scala and Redshift, I am trying to connect redshift with play framework. I have tried a couple of things but still not able to connect. i am using these configurations

```
db.default.driver=org.redshift.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:redshift://url:5439/myDb?"
db.default.username="name"
db.default.password="password"

play.modules.enabled += "scalikejdbc.PlayModule"
# scalikejdbc.PlayModule doesn't depend on Play's DBModule
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"
```

My SBT file looks like this

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/anorm
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"       % "3.2.1",
  "com.h2database"  %  "h2"                % "1.4.196",
  "ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"   % "1.2.3"
)
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon/redshift-jdbc41
resolvers += "redshift" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc4" % "1.2.10.1009
```

"

I am getting this error connecting DB

Comment: Please include the information on the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Redshift with Play Scala

Application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc4.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:redshift://url:5439/db"
db.default.username="name"
db.default.password="password"
```

SBT file

```
libraryDependencies += jdbc
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"                  % "3.2.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-config"           % "3.2.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-play-initializer" % "2.6.0-scalikejdbc-3.2"
)
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon/redshift-jdbc41
resolvers += "redshift" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc4" % "1.2.10.1009"
```

Controller

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db._
/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(db: Database, cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page.
   *
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def index() = Action {
    var outString = "Number is "
    val conn = db.getConnection()

    try {
      val stmt = conn.createStatement
      val rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 9 as testkey ")

      while (rs.next()) {
        outString += rs.getString("testkey")
      }
    } finally {
      conn.close()
    }
    Ok(outString)
//    implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
//
//    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
```